# How to center react native headerTitle *component* (not string)

Tags: react-native

For the life of me, I can't center the `headerTitle` component. Ideas?

```
class GroupSelectionScreen extends React.Component{
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {

        return {
            headerLeft: <View>
                <Image source={logoImg} style={{width:72, height:33, marginLeft:5}}/>
            </View>,
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: theme.colors.darkBlue,
                height: 75,
            },
            headerTitle: <View style={{
                alignItems: "center",
                flexDirection: 'row',

            }}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: statusColor, width: 15, height: 15, borderRadius: 8}}></View>
                <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 25}}>{username}</Text>
            </View>,
            headerRight: <SetStatusButton onPress={navigation.getParam('toggleSetStatus')}/>,
        };
    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `flexDirection:'row'` you will probably want to add the property `justifyContent:'center'` to center the content of the view horizontally

This is due to the fact that justifyContent works on the primary axis and alignItems work on the secondary axis. Setting the flexDirection as row changes the primary axis to be row.

> Adding flexDirection to a component's style determines the primary axis of its layout.
>
> Adding justifyContent to a component's style determines  the distribution of children along the primary axis.

You can see more in the docs

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox

Here is a snack https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/flexdirection

Each of the three views have `flexDirection: 'row'`

1. The first view has `justifyContent: 'center'` and the text is centred horizontally.
2. The second view has `alignItems: 'center'` and the text is centred vertically.
3. The third view has both `justifyContent: 'center'` and `alignItems: 'center'` and the text is centred horizontally and vertically

Here is an image of what it looks like

[image: image of three views showing text aligned in different ways]

And here is the code

```
<View>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: 100, width: 100, margin: 10}} >
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'cyan', height: 100, width: 100, margin: 10}} >
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor: 'forestgreen', height: 100, width: 100, margin: 10}} >
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

## Update

In `react-navigation` there appears to be a difference between how `headerTitle` given by the question poster is handled in Android and iOS.

In iOS the `headerTitle` centres vertically and horizontally, however in Android it centres only vertically and is aligned left. Obviously this is not ideal.

There is a way to make it work in both iOS and Android, simply

1. Wrap the original header in a `View` with `flex:1`
2. Make sure the original header's `View` has a style with `justifyContent: 'center'` and  `alignItems: 'center'`

Here is the code for the new `headerTitle`

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', width: 15, height: 15, borderRadius: 8}}/>
      <Text>Spencer</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Here is a snack showing it working https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/navigation-header

Comment: Alas, while this approach works for basic View components, it does not in the react header. Assume that I've tried the obvious :) - but thank you for the answer.

Comment: On SO you can’t assume the obvious. Many people don’t try the obvious.

Comment: So I think I have found a solution.